# Conditional analysis vs conditional logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, clogit

What is the difference between "conditional analysis" and "conditional logistic regression"?

It is also really hard to find out an easy example of that "conditional" means in this case...

Comment: Welcome user1261558, maybe you could be a bit more specific about the context in which you've encountered both type of analysis, it would make it easier to answer your question. You can also have a look at the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) on what to put in a question to maximize the chances of getting an answer. Conditional logistic regression is usually used to model choice between several alternatives (e.g. brand A or B at different prices), or in the context of a case/control situation assess characteristics found in the cases but not in the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comments by Antoine above, a conditional logistic regression is often used when the cases and controls are ***matched***. A conditional logistic regression can account for the fact that there is a dependence between how the patients were selected. Another example of when conditional logistic regression would be helpful is in the context of a dataset that has levels of strata or centers. In this context estimating the association between exposure (within a center or center) and an outcome is the goal.

A conditional analysis can have many meanings. I would need additional information to address this point. You may referring to doing analysis under a condition such as doing an analysis on people above the age of 60, or female patients in a data set. People often refer to these as subgroup analyses, if your study was not originally powered for investigating these associations.